# {page-break-after: always} not working when printing

Tags: html, css, page-break

EDIT: I just noticed this works in IE9, but not IE10 and Chrome.

We receive HTML formatted PO reports from one of our suppliers electronically.  We usually print these and before it would put 1 PO per page, but now it is not adding the page breaks.  I checked the html and I can't see why it wouldn't work all of a sudden.  This is the (poorly formatted) html:

```
<HEAD>
<STYLE TYPE='text/css'><!--
BR.breakhere {page-break-after: always}
.tb1{font:10pt Arial;}
.tb2{border-left:1px solid #000000; border-right:1px solid #000000;border-top: 1px  solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;}
.tb3{font:10pt Arial;border-left:1px solid #000000; border-right:1px solid #000000;border-top: 1px  solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;}
.tb4{font-size:8pt;}
--></STYLE>
</HEAD>
```

The page break is suppose to occur here:

```
<BR class=breakhere>
```

It occurs immediately after a TABLE element, the TABLE has an HR after the last TR (ugh).

```
<BR><HR style = "width:100%;height:10px;color:#000000"></TABLE><BR class=breakhere>
```

I want to contact them and mention this but I'm not sure if it is the code or something on our end? I've tried every browser, multiple printers and workstations, but can't get it to break pages.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this with a specific browser?

Comment: I've tried IE and Chrome with no breaks.

Comment: Ahh you made me think of something.  IE 9, the breaks work, IE 10 and Chrome do NOT work.  Updating question.

Comment: `page-break-after` is deprecated in favor of `break-after`.  See if `break-after: page` does the job.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbreak-after

Comment: `break-after: page` or `break-after: always` didn't work in either IE10 or chrome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been dealing with this too. It appears that using the page-break-after property in a break line is a no-no in IE10. According to Internet Explorer’s current documentation supporting CSS 2.1 Section 13.3.1, the page-break-after property does not support line break or header elements. See the remarks in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530842. I had to switch my code to use a div with the break after class but that doesn't seem to work in IE9 which is awesome.

Answer (score 28):

page-break is not enough for internet explorer by own. If u try this, you can see the result. I have same problem but I solved by this way.

```html
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
<div>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: OH MY GOD YOU ARE A LEGEND ! works perfect with the blank div afterwards

Comment: Somewhere at Microsoft is a plaque "An empty element can be ignored."

Comment: Tested and Works well!

Comment: WOW the style attribute worked! nothing else would, very strange

Comment: That makes no sense at all....but it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue I was having by adding the CSS below:

```
.new-page {
   page-break-after: always;
   page-break-inside: avoid;
   display: block;
}
```