# page-break-after: always doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I need the Div with class questions visual to come up on the second page while printing.

```
<html>
<head>
  
  <title>quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main_content">
            <h1 class="course_name">Course Name</h1>
        </div>
    <div class="exam_content">
      <div class="sub_content">
        <div class="exam_information">
          ----exam information----
            <div class="questions_visual >
                   -------questionsvisual------
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Style.css contains the following code

```
@media print {
   
  .questions_visual{
    page-break-after: always !important;
   
    }
}
```

I have tried the below code and it moved the whole div with class exam content to the next page while printing

```
div  {
    page-break-after: always !important;
   
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
<div>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Refer this link [{page-break-after: always} not working when printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989843/page-break-after-always-not-working-when-printing)